# Wireless point to point set up

Tags: networking, connection, wireless-bridge

I have looked at a variety of point to point equipment. Once I connect the sender side to my local ISP router via Ethernet my basic question is this:

On the receiver side do I have to have a router connected to the receiver piece to be able to wirelessly connect my computer, phone, TV, etc. to it? Or can I connect directly to it?

Comment: It depends on the product. Some products have the ability to work as both a point-to-point wireless bridge and AP at the same time, others don't.

Comment: Point-to-Point wireless connections are used to connect two locations together using directional antennas with line-of-sight, not for connecting two devices on the same local network. Why do you need it?

Comment: I have a small apartment about 60 feet from the main house and I want to be able to use my computer, smart tvs and have internet in the apartment.  I cant run an ethernet line underground, and it is to far for a normal powerline wifi, so I was looking a wireless ptp.  I just needed to know if I needed to buy a small router that I can plug into the wirelesss receiver so I can broadcast in the apartment.  I dont want to run ethernet all over the place

Comment: @RandyLPierce did you have a chance to look at the answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not need a "full" router, an AP (access point) which you attach to the receiver end of your WLAN bridge should be enough. However as Spiff points out in his comment there are devices that have an integrated AP on the receiver side.

You can use a end "consumer router" (with an integrated AP) if you want but you need to make sure to configure it correctly (e.g. put it in bridge mode).